# Batch Reprojection Tool, creating a variable with no value

Tags: python

This is for a school project. Questions regarding this project have been posted here previously (https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/131).

My teacher provided Python code for the class to insert to our script. Essentially it's drops the ".shp" from a file name and then appends "_projected.shp" afterwards. Here's the code I was provided and have in my script:

```
    rootName = ""
    if currentFC.endswith(".shp"):
        rootName = currentFC[:-4]
        newFC = str(rootName) + "_projected.shp"
```

Python is not liking the rootName variable's value (IOError: "" does not exist).
Since this code was given to me, I figured it would work but I also may be making a rookie mistake thinking that's how the variable was suppose to be declared.

I can provide the rest of my script if it is needed

Here is the traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonWin\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in **main**._*dict*_
  File "C:\Users\dan and kathryn\Desktop\school\programming\project2\project2.py", line 15, in 
    targetDesc = arcpy.Describe(targetFC)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy__init__.py", line 1190, in Describe
    return gp.describe(value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 374, in describe
    self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
IOError: "" does not exist

Comment: Your code, as shown, is doing no IO.  Are you sure that that error message comes from the part of the code that you have shown?  Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: I was hoping the one answer from @DuhProgrammer13 would solve everything. I saved the script, restarted my computer, and checked the script (kind of a ritual for me to restart...it solved many problems for me before). getting the same errors:

Comment: According to the stack trace, the error occurs during execution of `targetDesc = arcpy.Describe(targetFC)` which might indicate a problem with `targetFC`.  It appears, so far, that the error is unrelated to the source code that you have quoted.

Comment: @John1024, i've reviewed, researched (sorry, newbie), and stared at my script for awhile. I'm not sure what could be wrong? I will post my script up to where you say the problem is: #import modules
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#create paths
startFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
targetFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = startFolder

#get spatial reference for target FC
targetDesc = arcpy.Describe(targetFC)
targetSpat = targetDesc.spatialReference
targetName = targetSpat.Name

Comment: sorry, i am ALSO new to stackoverflow. not the best formatted comment i've seen on this website :'(

Comment: That indicates that the possibly problematic `targetFC` is set by `targetFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)` which means that it is coming directly from user input. You might check what input you are providing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason to declare rootName as `""` just saying `rootName = currentFC[:-4]` should be good enough especially if you are only using `rootName` on the line `newFC = str(rootName) + "_projected.shp"` So the following code to replace what you currently have should work.

```
if currentFC.endswith(".shp"):
    rootName = currentFC[:-4]
    newFC = str(rootName) + "_projected.shp"
```